# react-hook-form - empty input field after each submit

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm trying to understand how react-hook-form is working.
For this I created the following example:

```
import React from 'react';
import { useForm } from 'react-hook-form';

const InputForm = () => {
  const { register, handleSubmit } = useForm();

  const onSubmit = (data) => {
    console.log(data);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
        <Form.Group controlId='formBasicName'>
          <Form.Label>Name</Form.Label>
          <Form.Control
            type='text'
            name='name'
            ref={register}
          />
        </Form.Group>

        <Form.Group controlId='formBasicEmail'>
          <Form.Label>Email address</Form.Label>
          <Form.Control
            type='email'
            name='email'
            ref={register}
          />
          
        <Button className='submitBtn' type='submit'>
          Submit
        </Button>
      </Form>
    </>
  );
};

export default InputForm;
```

It works and if I submit the form I can see the data object in console.
The only problem is that after each submit the input boxes are still showing their value.
I want that after each submit the value of input boxes get empty.
That would be easy with useState, but now that I'm using react-hook-from, I don't know how to do that.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use this submit function:

```
const onSubmit = (data, e) => {
  e.target.reset();
};
```

Comment: this should not be the accepted answer - the React Hook Form docs clearly say to "NOT" reset during on submit:  https://react-hook-form.com/api/useform/reset

> It's recommended to not invoke reset inside onReset or onSubmit callback.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, for this simple context of this question, I believe we can use reset without any problem about the state. For async submit button, we just need to call reset after async is completed, it is the same with using `useEffect`.

Answer (score 35):

```
const InputForm = () => {
  const { register, handleSubmit, reset } = useForm();

  const onSubmit = (data) => {
    //...
    reset();
  };
```

Add it to the submit function

Answer (score 13):

PLEASE DO NOT accept the previous answers - the [RHF docs (see Rules & `Submit With Reset` tab)](https://react-hook-form.com/api/useform/reset) do not approve of `reset` inside the `onSubmit` callback:

> It's recommended to not invoke reset inside onReset or onSubmit callback.

The proper way is to have a `useEffect` that updates after all async work has completed:

```
const { reset } = useForm();
const [isSafeToReset, setIsSafeToReset] = useState(false);
  
useEffect(() => {
   if (!isSafeToReset) return;

   reset(result); // asynchronously reset your form values
}, [reset])

const onSubmit = async (data, e) => {
    try {
      await fetch('./api/formValues.json'); 
      setIsSafeToReset(true);
    } catch (e) {
      // do something w Err
    }
};
```

Comment: +1 this should be the accepted answer, it is explained clearly here https://react-hook-form.com/docs/useform/reset, in fact it's a bit cleaner now according to that documentation

Comment: 'isSafeToReset' should be set back to false after calling reset.

Answer (score 6):

React Hook Forms v7. This will clear the form data.

```
    const {register, handleSubmit, formState: { errors }, reset} = useForm();

    const onSubmit = (data, e) => {
        console.log(data)
        reset('', {
            keepValues: false,
        })
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code to reset the input fields

```
const onSubmit = (data, e) => {
  e.target[0].value = ''; // for name
  e.target[1].value = '';  // for email
};
```

Comment: Please explain how this might help, extend the code to minimal reproducible example,  in this state it is not helpful.