Next.js forms with server action: form gets emptied after submit
I'm using Next.js with form actions to set up a simple form that gets submitted to the server (with a react server action). I can see the form data being received on the server. Unfortunately, once the server action is finished, the form is emptied and the user input is lost.
Any idea why this happens?
Here's the code (I omitted the validation logic for simplicity):
/// Form.tsx
'use client';

import { submitForm } from '../actions/validateFormAction';

export function Form() {
  return (
    <form action={submitForm}>
      <input name="firstName" id="lastName" placeholder="First name" />
      <input name="firstName" id="lastName" placeholder="Last name" />
      <input type="submit" />
    </form>
  );
}

/// validateFormAction.ts
'use server';

export async function submitForm(data: FormData): Promise<void> {
  console.log('submitForm action', data);
}

Before submitting:

Server console output:
[1] submitForm action FormData {
[1]   [Symbol(state)]: [
[1]     {
[1]       name: '$ACTION_ID_4064bf5eac761f0b8f1771e13eed9498134e43b11e',
[1]       value: ''
[1]     },
[1]     { name: 'firstName', value: 'my first name' },
[1]     { name: 'firstName', value: 'my last name' }
[1]   ]
[1] }

After submitting:

The browser console mentions [Fast Refresh] rebuilding (although I don't know whether this is relevant).
Using "next": "15.0.2" and "react": "19.0.0-rc-02c0e824-20241028".
Any help would be appreciated.

I'm not sure about what i'll say here, just trying to help. But this behavior is probably not from react-hook-form (see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62741410/react-hook-form-empty-input-field-after-each-submit). It seems more like something related to SSR + Form submitting. When form is submitted it may trigger SSR's mechanism to update the page (which is why it's rebuilding). When the page is reloaded, the form is cleared. If you're wanting to stop this behavior, maybe catching the event and preventing the propagation solves it

@AlexanderSantos you are right, when removing RHF, it shows the same behavior. I'll update the question to reflect this.

you can either save the input in a react state through onChange event or you can get the data in the action and send it back with const [state, action] = useActionState()

@Evilolipop that seems to be the correct conclusion. However, it worked fine in Next 14, and not anymore in Next 15 :/

@fikkatra It still works I think. const [state, action] = useActionState(ac, initialState), then <input name="firstName" id="firstName" defaultValue={state.firstName} />

@Evilolipop it works in Next 15 if you write code to store the form state (either with useState or by mirroring the state back after submitting, then bind the input to the state object, like you did). In v14, it worked out of the box, without doing that.
